# Calculating Mean, Median and Percentile in SQL

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I'm new to SQL and trying to calculate the mean, median and tp90 for a similar table as below-

```
name year month id sum  
x1  2019    1   a1  46  
x1  2019    1   a2  21  
x1  2019    1   a3  7  
x1  2019    1   a4  25  
x1  2019    1   a5  24  
x2  2019    1   b1  33  
x2  2019    1   b2  9  
x2  2019    1   b3  8  
x2  2019    1   b4  20  
x2  2019    1   b5  15
```

I'm looking for an output like this-

```
(name, year, month, avg, median, tp90 )=
(x1, 2019,  1, 25, 24,   37.6)
```

I can do this using Excel but having difficulty generalizing it to the entire data set with a SQL code.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do just use aggregation:

```
select name, year, month, avg(sum) as average,
       percentile_cont(0.5) within group (order by sum) as median,  -- or median()
       percentile_cont(0.9) within group (order by sum) as percentile_90
from t
group by name, year, month;
```

The key function here is [`percentile_cont()`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_PERCENTILE_CONT.html).  In many databases, this is only a window function  It is happily an aggregation function in Redshift.